# Оптимизация алгоритма для задачи на перебор

Tags: python, алгоритм

Простая задачка из олимпиады, но мое квадратичное решение не проходит ограничение по времени. Можно ли как нибудь оптимизировать работу моего алгоритма? Условие и свое решение прикладываю ниже :

> Лайнландия состоит из `n` городов, которые расположены на оси `Ox`.
> Координата `i`-го из городов равна `xi`.
>
> Поликарп прошел от одного города до другого по прямой кратчайшим
> образом. Он утверждает, что прошел расстояние `d`.
>
> Выведите количество пар городов, что Поликарп мог пройти от одного к
> другому. Иными словами, между которыми расстояние составляет ровно `d`.

> **Входные данные**

> В первой строке записаны два целых числа `n`, `d` `(2 ≤ n ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ d ≤ 10^9)`.
> Вторая строка содержит координаты n городов — последовательность целых
> чисел `x1, x2, ..., xn` `( - 10^9 ≤ xi ≤ 10^9)`. Все `xi` — различны.
>
> **Выходные данные**

> Выведите искомое количество пар городов. Пары,
> отличающиеся только порядком городов, следует считать одной и той же
> парой.

Мое решение:

```
n,d = map(int, input().split())

l = list(map(int, input().split()))

l.sort()
ans = 0
for i in l:
    if i+d in l:
        ans+=1
print(ans)
```

Comment: Ну, я бы после сортировки (из условия непонятно, отсортированы данные или нет... похоже, что нет) координат шел слева направо, с двумя индексами, от первого до того, который превысит d. тогда смещал бы левый индекс, пока расстояние не станет меньше d, и опять двигал бы правую сторону. Т.о., поиск пар выполнялся бы за O(n). А общая сложность — O(n\*log n).

Comment: Тут даже сортировать не надо, можно просто сделать мапу с координатами ключами и индексами значениями. И для каждой координаты x в мапе искать ключ x+d, если такой есть - то перебрать все пары городов с координатой. Сложность при этом будет линейная.

Comment: @tym32167, зачем же мапу, сеты достаточно. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да я по диагонали прочитал и подумал про пары. Для подсчета просто количества да, сета за глаза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта. Первый с двумя курсорами, второй с ассоциативным массивом.

```
# x - отсортированный список
def find_pair(x, d, left, right):
    while right < len(x):
        s = x[right] - x[left]
        if s == d:
            return (left, right)
        if s > d:
            left += 1
        if s < d:
            right +=1
    return (-1,-1)

def count1_pairs(x,d):
    x = sorted(x)
    cnt = 0
    l,r = 0,0
    while True:
        l,r = find_pair(x,d,l,r)
        if l < 0:
            break
        else:
            l += 1
            r += 1
            cnt +=1
    return cnt

# Второй вариант
def count2_pairs(x,d):
    mx = { x : i for i,x in enumerate(x)}
    cnt = 0
    for coord in mx.keys():
        if (coord + d) in mx:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

Тестовые данные: 50 тысяч городов с координатами от 0 до 500 млн.
Тестовое расстояние равно расстоянию между городами с номерами 33332 и 10000

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.choice(500_000_000, size = 50_000)
d = abs(x[len(x)//3*2] - x[len(x)//5])
```

Время работы функции `count1_pairs` : 52.2 ms ± 2.85 ms

Время работы функции `count2_pairs` : 18.7 ms ± 356 µs

Окончания работы вашей функции я не дождался.

Comment: Сердечно благодарю Вас за столь ясное написание кода, буду продолжать учиться, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Вот оптимальное по времени решение. Единственное принципиальное отличие от вашего - это замена списка на множество. Поиск в списке требует времени пропорционального длине списка. Поиск в множестве делается за константу.

```
n,d = map(int, input().split())

l = set(map(int, input().split()))

ans = 0
for i in l:
    if i+d in l:
        ans+=1
print(ans)
```

P.S. Сортировку я убрал - она не применима к множествам. В вашем варианте сортировка тоже была не нужна.

Comment: На тех же самых тестовых данных время работы 14.4 ms ± 410 µs

Comment: @PakUula, спасибо. Как ваша рука?

Comment: Ещё месяц в гипсе. Но уже наловчился попадать по нужным клавишам большим пальцем правой руки - это единственный подвижный палец, все остальные упакованы. Большое достижение, между прочим. На моей корейской клавиатуре нет русских букв. Слепая однопальцевая печать ))

Comment: @PakUula, выздоравливайте! P.S. А по коду не скажешь что одним пальцем...

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Действительно, я совсем забыл про множества, буду совершенствоваться

Comment: @Sinka обратите внимание на особенности предложенных решений. `count1_pairs` легко обобщается на вещественные числа и точность плюс минус эпсилон. `count2_pairs` позволяет не только считать число пар, но и выводить сами пары городов. А решение из принятого ответа максимально оптимизировано под условия задачи.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо! Что касается кода - сам в шоке ))